# SQL data restore and space issue

Tags: mysql

I had some tables on my database that have duplicate values, in order to get rid of those I made a small program that finds duplicates remove them and write new rows.
By mistake, I commented the line that writes rows to database, and the only commands that were passed are the DELETE ones.

The reason I wanted to filter is that the database was taking too much space, now after that I lost all data I still see no space freed.

After operation, I had all rows deleted from the table, but the space that data has occupied remains the same.

My question is if I still can restore data in this case, and why space isn't getting freed after DELETE operations were done?

Comment: Unless you have backup your deleted data is not recoverable.

Comment: There are tools that independently work directly with the table file and allow you to copy data from there, even soft-deleted ones. But they are all paid.. So save the copy of your file with deleted data.

Comment: Deleting data from a table won't release the space that it currently uses.  You'll need to OPTIMIZE it afterwards.  https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/optimize-mysql-table-and-shrink-the-file-size/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed @melvinlusk 's solution, So I added an optimizations steps in my programs and now the space is getting freed after optimization, and I gave up restoring my data.